# How to keep % in sprintf?

Tags: r, printf

How can I keep a % symbol in string using `sprintf()`?

For now, i'm using `sprintf('%.2f%s', runif(1, 0, 100), '%')`, but there should be another way.

Comment: you can also do `sprintf('%.2f\\d', runif(1, 0, 100), 42)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sprintf("%.2f%%", runif(1, 0, 100))
```

Use `%%` to 'escape' the %.  This is explained in the help file

```
?sprintf
```

Comment: I read the help before post here, but missed this part :( thanks!

Comment: I suspect the reason the answer is not "\%" is that `sprintf` gets handed off to the OS version of that function.